# log4net creates 2 log files instead of expected one, when log4net is configure both in mine and 3rd party dll

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, white-framework

I have 2 projects in my solution, both of class library type.

1. Actions: Project which contains actions, written using White (UI automation framework over MS UI Automation)
2. Tests: Project with test fixtures and test methods, using MbUnit

I decided to add logging using log4net for both projects. The log4net configuration I'm using is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"
          value="c:/AutomationLog/Automation_%date{dd.MM.yy_HH.mm.ss}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Once" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date{HH:mm:ss,fff} %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger name="root">
    <level value="OFF" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

I would like that one file is created each run (one per fixture suite run). But two files are created:

> Automation_27.01.13_07.33.53.log
>
> Automation_27.01.13_07.33.53.log.1

After investigation I found that log is spitted into 2nd file each time in the same place -- when actions contain types from White is called. Looks like it happens due to White also uses log4net internally.

So, I guess, situation is like this:

1. I have a class which initializes log4net
2. I start the fixtures suite
3. In the tests project there is a class which runs 1st, which contains `Log.Info("...")`
4. log file is created
5. text is appended until..
6. 1st action which references White's types is run from tests project
7. At this stage a new file is created
8. I guess it happens because of inside White Dlls there is another call to initialize log4net, it is hard coded inside

Any idea how to prevent log splitting without modifying the code of White (3rd party dlls)?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by just renaming the config file, white looks for log4net.config name. But I still haven't got the answer - is it possible how to force log4net to be initialized just once, and skip future attempts.